# Two sums in Java from leetcode

Tags: java, arrays

I am working in leetcode problems. I just solved the following problem:

Given an array of integers, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number.

The function twoSum should return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target, where index1 must be less than index2. Please note that your returned answers (both index1 and index2) are not zero-based.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.

Input: numbers={2, 7, 11, 15}, target=9
Output: index1=1, index2=2

My code is here:

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        
            int len = numbers.length;

        int[] result = new int[2] ;
        int number1 = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            number1 = numbers[i];

            for(int j = i+1; j < len; j++)
            {

                sum = number1+numbers[j];       
                if(sum == target)
                {
                    result[0]=i;
                    result[1]=j;
                }
            }
        
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It gives me a time limited exceeded; however, I think this solution might work. Can anyone tell me if this solution is good enough?

Comment: The problem is that your current algorithm is O(N^2) and it will take too much time in an array of 100 elements. Try to change your algorithm to use an O(Nlog2N) algorithm or even better, move this into a linear algorithm.

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-solution-of-two-sum-in-java/

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thank you, but the solution will work. The problem is that it is not efficient.

Comment: Again, it's not that your current solution doesn't solve the problem, but your algorithm is **too slow**.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your solution has O(n*n) time complexity. and this problem can be solved by O(n) time complexity if you make use of Map

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i =0; i< nums.length; i++) {
            if(map.containsKey(target - nums[i])){
                return new int[]{map.get(target - nums[i]), i};
            }else {
                map.put(nums[i], i);
            }
        }
        return new int[]{-1,-1};
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/).

Of course there is an efficient solution. **Time complexity is O(n)**.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
        
        /* 2, 7, 11, 15  ==  target=9
         * 0  1   2   3  => 4
         *  
         *    --HasMap--
         *  key   value(index)
         *   2  ->  0
         *   7  ->  1
         *
        */
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
           int expectedKey = target - nums[i];
           if(map.containsKey(expectedKey)) {
               return new int[]{map.get(expectedKey), i};
           }
           map.put(nums[i], i);
        }
             
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Solution");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This MAY reduce the timing issue, but I cannot guarantee that it would solve the problem entirely!

You can `return` the solution (`result`) as soon as it is found, as it is stated in the problem that exactly one solution exists for a given problem, i.e.

```
if(sum == target)
{
    result[0]=i;
    result[1]=j;
    return result;
}
```

rather than continuing to search the rest of the input.

Comment: No tuna, actually the time complexity matters here! not where you break the loop!

Comment: @Dinal24 I know; I was just pointing out a minor optimization. (Can I assume that you too are attempting this problem right now? ;) )

Comment: Nice :) Care to include the solution (or maybe the strategy) as an answer here?

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-solution-of-two-sum-in-java/
maybe no need for it as this has the answer!

Answer (score 0):

public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
int[] indices = new int[2];

```
    for(int x = 0; x < nums.length ; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < nums.length ; y++){
            if(x != y && nums[x] + nums[y] == target){
            indices[0] = x;
            indices[1] = y;
            return indices;
        }
        }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer for LeetCode question Two Sums.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] resultArray = new int[2];

        for(int i=0; i<=nums.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<=nums.length - 1; j++){
            int sum = nums[i] + nums[j];

            if(i != j && sum == target){
                resultArray[0] = i;
                resultArray[1] = j;
                return resultArray;
                //System.out.println("\n[" + nums[i] + "," + nums[i+1] + "]");
            }
        }
        }
            return resultArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] a = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                    a[0] = i;
                    a[1] = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not appreciably different from the original solution in the question, and runs in O(N*N) time. OPs problem is that this algorithm is too slow.